# Xamarin Forms Preferences Stopped Working after iOS 14.4.2 Update

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, preferences

The app is developed in Visual Studio Windows with XCode on iMac and before 14.4.2 everything was working perfect, but after 14.4.2 update the app started to crash. I suspect Native Settings (Xamarin.Forms.Preferences), because our try-catch blocks do not register and iOS Simulator is working fine.

Comment: You could post the relevant code , which will been helpful to find out the cause .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT it's this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin/ios was working fine before 14.4.2 update